# Overlapping entity's text (AutoCAD/C#)

Tags: c#, text, autocad, overlapping

I'm try to modify `MText.Contents` entity but as you can see the new string which is "123" exactly overlapped on the original one, H e l l o.

[image]

Here is the code (I've tried the commented part but no luck so far).

```
//BlockTableRecord btrr = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(SymbolUtilityServices.GetBlockModelSpaceId(curdb), OpenMode.ForWrite);
BlockTableRecord btrr = bt[BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace].GetObject(OpenMode.ForWrite) as BlockTableRecord;

foreach (ObjectId id in btrr)
{
    Entity currentEntity = tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForWrite, false, true) as Entity;
    //Entity currentEntity = tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForWrite, true) as Entity;
    if (currentEntity == null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (currentEntity.GetType() == typeof(MText))
    {
        if (((MText)currentEntity).Contents == "H e l l o")
        {
            //currentEntity.UpgradeOpen();             
            ((MText)currentEntity).Contents = "123";
            //currentEntity.DowngradeOpen();

            //    TextEditor textEditor = TextEditor.CreateTextEditor((MText)currentEntity);
            //    textEditor.SelectAll();
            //    TextEditorSelection selection = textEditor.Selection;
            //    selection.InsertString("123");
            //    textEditor.Close(TextEditor.ExitStatus.ExitSave);

            Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.ShowAlertDialog(((MText)currentEntity).Contents + "--MText");

        }       
    }
}
```

`AlertDialog` text is 123 which is new.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
    [CommandMethod("TEST")]
    public static void Test()
    {
        var db = HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
        using (var tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            var ms = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(
                SymbolUtilityServices.GetBlockModelSpaceId(db), OpenMode.ForRead);
            foreach (ObjectId id in ms)
            {
                if (id.ObjectClass == RXObject.GetClass(typeof(MText)))
                {
                    var mtext = (MText)tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForRead);
                    if (mtext.Contents == "H e l l o")
                    {
                        tr.GetObject(id, OpenMode.ForWrite);
                        mtext.Contents = "123";
                    }
                }
            }
            tr.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually the DWG file downloaded from a server(Stream, bytes...) and after explode and so on. I've found the problem which you can see in Answer. Also i liked your approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
                        BlockTableRecord btrec = (BlockTableRecord)blkid.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead);
                        btrec.UpgradeOpen();

                        btrec.DowngradeOpen();

                        foreach (ObjectId index in btrec)
                        {
                            Entity en = (Entity)index.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead);
                            AttributeDefinition adef = en as AttributeDefinition;

                            if (adef != null)
                            {
                                ed.WriteMessage("\n" + adef.Tag);
                            }

                        foreach (ObjectId id in btrec)
                        {
                            Entity currentEntity = (Entity)id.GetObject(OpenMode.ForWrite);

                            if (currentEntity == null)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                            if (currentEntity.GetType() == typeof(MText))
                            {
                                if (((MText)currentEntity).Contents == "H E L L O")
                                {
                                    ((MText)currentEntity).Contents = "123";                                      
                                }
                            }

                        }
```